# What is the JPanel/Graphics method paintComponent?

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, graphics

So I'm trying to learn Java graphics and this bit of code has me perplexed. I don't understand a couple things here:

1. Why is `paintComponenet` used twice for the name of the method and as
   we call a method from super (`JPanel`)?
2. What is `Graphics g`, isn't it just a reference variable for an object
   of `Graphics` since we don't set it equal to `= new Graphics();`?
3. Why does the method name in my class have to be `paintComponent` to
   call upon the method `paintComponent` from `JPanel` or super?
4. The method in my class `paintComponent` takes the parameter of a
    Graphics object but when does `paintComponent` even get called and
     when is the parameter of `Graphics` inserted?

Essentially I need someone to explain this code to me.

```
//note this is all in a class that extends JPanel, my JPanel is later placed in 
//a JFrame which is run through main
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
        {
            int width = getWidth();             
            int height = getHeight();         

            super.paintComponent(g);   

            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(10, 10, 200, 200); 
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.drawRect(10, 10, 200, 200); 
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is paintComponenet used twice, for the name of the method and as we call a method from super (JPannel)

It's not "used" twice. It is overridden once, but you want to call the parent (JPanel) class's super method so that you're sure that it does its own house-keeping painting, including painting its children and clearing out any dirty bits from the screen.

> What is Graphics g, isn't it just a reference variable for an object of Graphics since we don't set it equal to = new Graphics();

It's a Graphics *parameter*. You don't set it = `new Graphics()` because the JVM does this for you. It calls the method behind the scenes when needed, and provides the parameter.

> Why does the method name in my class have to be paintComponent to call upon the method paintComponent from JPannel or super

It has to override the super's method so that the JVM calls the right method when it wants to draw the GUI.

> The method in my class paintComponent takes the parameter of a Graphics object but when does paintComponent even get called and when is the parameter of Graphics inserted.

Again, it is called by the JVM when either your program wants to repaint the GUI, such as when you call `repaint()` or when the operating system wants to repaint a window such as if a window is minimized and restored.

You really really want to read the graphics tutorials:

- [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html): introductory tutorial to Swing graphics
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html): advanced tutorial on Swing graphics

Comment: Isn't the [inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) tutorial the one he really wants to read? :)

Comment: Okay thanks, this helped. I need a little more time to think about this, but tomorrow ill come back to this post and ask a little more

Comment: @AshwinGupta: but please don't ask any more until you've read/studied the two tutorials that I've linked to at the end of my answer.

Comment: @AshwinGupta: Also, if you have further questions, please create a *new* question. If you add more information to this question after it has been answered, not many people will see it.

Answer (score 5):

> 1) Why is paintComponenet used twice, for the name of the method and as we call a method from super (JPannel)

Here the line super.paintComponent(...), means we want the JPanel to be drawn the usual Java way first (this usually depends on the opaque property of the said JComponent, if it's true, then it becomes the responsibility on the part of the programmer to fill the content area with a fully opaque color. If it is false, then the programmer is free to leave it untouched. So in order to overcome the hassle assoicated with this contract, super.paintComponent(g) is used, since it adheres to the rules, and performs the same task, depending upon whether the opaque property is true or false).

> 2) What is Graphics g, isn't it just a reference variable for an
>   object of Graphics since we don't set it equal to = new Graphics();
>   and
>   4) The method in my class paintComponent takes the parameter of a
>   Graphics object but when does paintComponent even get called and when
>   is the parameter of Graphics inserted

`paintComponent` method is where all of your painting code should be placed. It is true that this method will be invoked when it is time to paint, but painting actually begins higher up the class heirarchy, with the `paint` method (defined by java.awt.Component.) This method will be executed by the painting subsystem whenever you component needs to be rendered. Its signature is:

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
```

javax.swing.JComponent extends this class and further factors the paint method into three separate methods, which are invoked in the following order:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
protected void paintBorder(Graphics g)
protected void paintChildren(Graphics g)
```

The API does nothing to prevent your code from overriding paintBorder and paintChildren, but generally speaking, there is no reason for you to do so. For all practical purposes paintComponent will be the only method that you will ever need to override